# Data filtering on form generates "Could not find field"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I spent half day trying to figure out why appears an error messagebox

> Could not find field 'TransactionTypeID'

in my 
[database](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aozmmr49648h8fv/Database1.accdb?dl=0). If you open `Form1`, then apply any filter on column `TransactionTypeID` using header (for instance, uncheck Blanks) and then try to open sorting/filtering for second column, appears error message.
Error disappears if I convert combobox to text box or remove from form select table `Tenants1`. I use Access 2010 32 bit. In this example I simplified tables as much as possible, database created from scratch, data imported, compact/repair doesn't help.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The built-in datasheet form filtering works in a wrong way if tables joined this way:

```
SELECT VouchersMain1.VDate, VouchersMain1.TransactionTypeID
FROM Tenant1 INNER JOIN VouchersMain1 ON Tenant1.TenantID = VouchersMain1.TenantID;
```

If I reverse tables join direction, built-in filtering works fine:

```
SELECT VouchersMain1.VDate, VouchersMain1.TransactionTypeID
FROM VouchersMain1 INNER JOIN Tenant1 ON VouchersMain1.TenantID = Tenant1.TenantID;
```

Looks like this is another Access bug.

Also, thanks @Munsterlander, problem disappears if form's recordsource replaced by saved query instead of SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing your field as Forms!FORMNAME!CONTROLNAME.  I assume, based off what you wrote, you are trying to filter a query based on what is selected in the combobox.

Comment: What do you mean under "referencing"? Form doesn't contain any code at all. And yes, I'm trying to filter a query based on what selected in the combobox. Similar queries in other databases work fine.

Comment: Edit your query.  In criteria box below your field, you will need to type in what I wrote but use your form name and the combobox name for controlname.  This way, the query can find your control.  The error is saying it can't find the specified control because you have to reference it via the long name.

Comment: I downloaded your db and see no error. Pressing _Filter_ filters, pressing again unfilters.

Comment: I just downloaded your db as well to see what you are doing.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Gustav is correct in that it does what it is supposed to do.  Your question indicates you are filtering the form and the error is because you filtered your form data out.  MS Access is doing what it is supposed to do.  If you execute the filter on the tables themselves, everything works like you want.  Ideally, you would not be using a form in datasheet view without first creating an actual query and setting up the criteria filter as I previously wrote.  Much more efficient use of Access.

Comment: I'm filtering using built-in datasheet filtering feature (small arrow in column header, like in Excel). If you delete from form's query table Tenants1 or replace it by any other table, filtering works fine! I don't understand how Tenants1 can affect filtering. Probably it's a bug or I still don't understand something.

Comment: Looks like I found the problem. The form works in wrong way if tables joined this way: `FROM Tenant1 INNER JOIN VouchersMain1 ON...` and works OK if this way: `FROM VouchersMain1 INNER JOIN Tenant1 ON...` Quite strange, especially if selected columns are the same: `SELECT VouchersMain1.VDate, VouchersMain1.TransactionTypeID` Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the table Tenants1 from your form RecordSource (this table is not necessary and do not exposes fields in the resulting query).

You would also note that your recordsource is set (by Access) ReadOnly (bad design, no join defined). Try to add a couple of Records in the Tenant1 table, say it David and Nathan.

You will find that now your query will output 6 records (and not 2), because the query (with no joins) list one row for all records of table Tenant1 (3) and one row for each record of table VouchersMain1 (2), giving a total of 2*3=6 rows.

Comment: This is just simplified variant of quite complex query with more than 2 tables, all tables joined and select returns dozens fields, including Tenants. When I reversed join between these two tables, whole query worked fine.

Comment: Ok, fine. I downloaded your database and no join was defined between your 2 tables ...